# How to check Create Table SQl query in DBFit?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dbfit

I have created a table using sqlplus without any data.  How can I write a test in DBFit to check if a table with that name exists?

Comment: I do not know what dbfit is. A quick google tell me it's a testing too. So what aspect of your table do you want to check?

Comment: DbFit is a unit testing tool . I'm are checking queries like select * from using dbfit . now, i want to check create table in dbFit

Comment: Ok, so you created you table in sqlplus. What are you now checking? That it exists? That's it has the right name? That it's empty?

Comment: checking if the table exists with that name

Answer (score 1):

you can use Query Stats for this.

syntax   is like this.

```
!| Query  Stats |  
|   query     |    is empty?|

|select * from user_tables where table_name = 'table_name'         |false          |
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want an assertion that the table exists. Simply a matter of checking of the Oracle data dictionary.

Without knowing DBfit syntax the query would be:

```
select count(*) 
from user_tables
where table_name = 'YOUR_TEST_TABLE';
```

If that returns 1 the table exists with that name. If 0 it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer from APC, in DBFIt you would do something like this:

!|Query| !- select count(*) KNT
              from user_tables
             where table_name = 'YOUR_TEST_TABLE' -!|
|KNT|
|1|

Although, if its not a table of your creation, you may wish to use all_tables instead of user_tables.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, please highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar or using Ctrl+K on your keyboard to nicely format and syntax highlight it!